# Excel Macro Transpose only few columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet looks like this: "Sheet1" & "Sheet2" and I wanted the result as shown in "Sheet3".

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYt1U.jpg)

Eventually I would like to put a "Button" in a separate sheet (Control Panel) and when clicking on it I need to combine the data from "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" with the transpose effect as shown in "Sheet3".

How can I automate this using macro since there are ~2000 "rows" in Sheet 1 and ~1000 in Sheet 2. I'm new to macro so hopefully I can make this automated otherwise I'm copying and pasting all of them manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Where does the **Access** field come from ??

Comment: Access field is the new field we need to create while performing the transpose and likewise with Department as well.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to use a function that returns the last row of a worksheet:

```
Public Function funcLastRow(shtTarget As Worksheet, Optional iColLimit As Integer = -1) As Long

    If iColLimit = -1 Then
        iColLimit = 256
    End If

    Dim rowMaxIndex As Long
    rowMaxIndex = 0

    Dim ctrCols As Integer
    For ctrCols = 1 To iColLimit
    If shtTarget.Cells(1048576, ctrCols).End(xlUp).Row > rowMaxIndex Then
            rowMaxIndex = shtTarget.Cells(1048576, ctrCols).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next ctrCols

    funcLastRow = rowMaxIndex

End Function
```

You could use it simply like so:

```
Dim lLastRow As Long
lLastRow = funcLastRow(Sheets(1))
```

Please let us know if that worked for you thanks

Comment: Thank you Mike!! I tried using your suggestion but could not able to implement it correctly. May be I'm not able to understand the solution provided correctly since I never worked with VBA before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an all formula solution (No Macro)

Data is in Sheet1 A to I and Sheet2 A to G

I am assuming you have only 6 departments. although if you have additional, the formulas need very little or may be no modification.

In Sheet 3

Get the userID repeated six times

```
A2 = INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,1+QUOTIENT(ROW()-ROW($A$2)+6,6))
```

Get Name, Gender & Country

```
B2 = VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$I$3000,COLUMNS($A$1:B$1),FALSE)

C2 = VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$I$3000,COLUMNS($A$1:C$1),FALSE)

D2 = VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$I$3000,COLUMNS($A$1:D$1),FALSE)
```

Get Access to department. The `"" & ...` is to avoid 0 in case the resulting cell was blank.

`E2 = "" & IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!$A$1:$I$1=F2))>0,HLOOKUP(F2,Sheet1!$A$1:$I$3000,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3000,0),FALSE),HLOOKUP(F2,Sheet2!$A$1:$G$3000,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3000,0),FALSE`))

`F2:F7` the departments are Input manually (no formula). `F8` is linked to `F2` so that the depts repeat when dragged down

```
G2 = "" & IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!$A$1:$I$1=F2))>0,INDEX(Sheet1!$I$1:$I$3000,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3000,0)),INDEX(Sheet2!$G$1:$G$3000,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3000,0)))
```

[image: Screenshot of result]

If you need, I can prepare a google sheet to demo. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you nightcrawler23!! This is indeed a good solution with using formulas but the challenge assigned to me is to automate this whole process with a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

This code works very well for Transpose and concatenate of big data.

```css
Sub ConcatData()
Dim X As Double
Dim DataArray(5000, 2) As Variant
Dim NbrFound As Double
Dim Y As Double
Dim Found As Integer
Dim NewWks As Worksheet

Cells(1, 1).Select
Let X = ActiveCell.Row
Do While True
If Len(Cells(X, 1).Value) = Empty Then
Exit Do
End If
If NbrFound = 0 Then
NbrFound = 1
DataArray(1, 1) = Cells(X, 1)
DataArray(1, 2) = Cells(X, 2)
Else
For Y = 1 To NbrFound
Found = 0
If DataArray(Y, 1) = Cells(X, 1).Value Then
DataArray(Y, 2) = DataArray(Y, 2) & ", " & Cells(X, 2)
Found = 1
Exit For
End If
Next
If Found = 0 Then
NbrFound = NbrFound + 1
DataArray(NbrFound, 1) = Cells(X, 1).Value
DataArray(NbrFound, 2) = Cells(X, 2).Value
End If
End If
X = X + 1
Loop

Set NewWks = Worksheets.Add
NewWks.Name = "SummarizedData"
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Names"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Results"
X = 2
For Y = 1 To NbrFound
Cells(X, 1).Value = DataArray(Y, 1)
Cells(X, 2).Value = DataArray(Y, 2)
X = X + 1
Next
Beep
MsgBox ("Summary is done!")
End Sub
```